# switch statement with nested if/else gives multiple outputs in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm writing a pretty simple program for my first-year C++ class, where I utilize `switch` statements to get a correct output depending on what two numbers and what special character is used between them (adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing). The program uses a nested `if` statement in the division case to check if the second number entered is zero, and a `default` statement if none of the correct special characters are used.

The problem lies in the fact that if the user divides by zero, or uses an incorrect symbol, the console will display the intended error, but also the result, when it's only supposed to show the message.

I understand why it's displaying both lines, but I don't know of any way to fix it. I'm not allowed to change the `switch` statement to an `if` statement, and I'm not allowed to use additional functions or arrays.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char operatr;

    double operand1 = 0,
           operand2 = 0,
           result = 0;
    cout << "Enter a binary expression of the form: operand operator operand ";
    cin >> operand1 >> operatr >> operand2;
    cout << endl << endl
         << "C.S.1428.002" << endl
         << "Lab Section: L17" << endl
         << "10/14/20" << endl << endl;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);

    switch ( operatr )
    {
    case '+':
        result = operand1 + operand2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = operand1 - operand2;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = operand1 * operand2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if ( operand2 == 0)
        {
            cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << " " << "Division by zero produces an undefined result" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            result = operand1 / operand2;
            break;
        }
    default:
        cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << "  Encountered unknown operator." << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << " = " << result << endl;

    system("PAUSE>NUL");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Incorporate your error message into result and populate it only when appropriate. Keep only one `cout` at the end.

Comment: Although [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) should normally not be used if there is a better alternative, in this case, I do recommend using it. You can use it to skip the `cout` line which prints the result.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No no no no. Why? This is easily solvable with a simple bool, error status or an exception, why resort to such measures? there are very few valid use cases for goto, e.g high performance parsers, this is definitely not one of them

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: Personally, consider a `goto` to be the lesser evil than the introduction of an additional (unnecessary) variable. However, I guess this is a matter of taste (and performance requirements).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Unnecessary? It makes the intent perfectly clear and has semantic meaning. You just suggested using `goto` to a first year beginner which struggles with simple control flow. Think about that. Do you want to maintain his code?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Just to take away some performance anxiety: https://godbolt.org/z/6zd9vW Boolean flag gets translated to goto by gcc (i decided to replace iostreams with printf to reduce clutter abit)

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: I see nothing wrong with teaching someone how to use `goto`, provided that sufficient warning is provided that it is considered bad programming style to use it in cases in which other control flow statements can do the job just as well.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: Yes, it is impressive what compilers are able to optimize away nowadays. However, I believe compilers are only able to analyze a program up to a certain depth, so they are better at optimizing shorter code and not so good at optimizing larger code. Even if performance were not an issue, I personally consider the code with the `goto` to be a bit cleaner than introducing an additional variable. However, as stated before, this is probably a matter of taste. I understand that many other programmers feel differently.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to use a `bool` flag to signal a successful operation which would then be used as a condition to print the result:

```
//...

bool flag = true;

switch (operatr)
{
case '+':
    result = operand1 + operand2;
    break;
case '-':
    result = operand1 - operand2;
    break;
case '*':
    result = operand1 * operand2;
    break;
case '/':
    if (operand2 == 0)
    {
        cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << " "
             << "Division by zero produces an undefined result" << endl;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        result = operand1 / operand2;
    }
    break;
default:
    cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << "  Encountered unknown operator." << endl;
    flag = false;
    break;

}
if (flag)
    cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << " = " << result << endl;

//...
```

You could also use a [`try block`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch), which I suspect can fall into the category of things you can't do, nonetheless it's worth taking a look at for future reference.

Or as suggested by [@VladFeinstein in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64326443/6865932) just return from the switch in case an error occurs given that it's a one of execution.

Comment: Simple and elegant.  But if `true` is the norm why not initialize the flag to true and set it to false in the sole case where it's needed?

Comment: @Christophe, advice taken.

Comment: See my answer for a solution which avoids introducing an additional variable by using the (highly controversial) `goto` statement instead.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel forget about goto unless you have to write C code for the unix kernel.  Instead use a try { your switch+ print result} catch() {error processing}

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You make a subrutine where you can return from instead of falling for the quicker, easier more seductive `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

In such a simple case, where there are no recovery from those input errors, why not just `return 1;` instead of `break;`?

Answer (score -1):

Although [the `goto` statement should generally not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) if there is a better alternative, in this case, I believe it is appropriate to use it. The alternatives would be code duplication or the introduction of an additional variable. See the other answer for a solution which avoids using `goto` by using an additional variable.

Here is my solution which uses `goto`:

```
int main()
{
    [...]

    default:
        cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << "  Encountered unknown operator." << endl;
        goto bad_input;
    }

    cout << operand1 << " " << operatr << " " << operand2 << " = " << result << endl;

bad_input:
    system("PAUSE>NUL");

    return 0;
}
```

Just remember not to make it a habit to use `goto` everywhere, as this is considered very bad programming style. Always look for better alternatives, such as `for`, `while`, `do`...`while`, `break`, `continue`, etc. That will make your code easier to read, both for yourself and for other people. There are only very rare cases in which the use of `goto` is appropriate.

Comment: Downvoting for the suggestion of `goto`. Modern C++ guidelines have many workarounds and this day and age has no place for it.

Comment: @Casey: Yes, there are, as you say, many "workarounds" for `goto`. It is good that these workarounds are being posted as answers. However, why should only workaround solutions be upvoted and non-workaround solutions be downvoted? Would it not be more appropriate that both types of solutions be presented as answers, in which the advantages and disadvantages of both types of solutions are highlighted?

Comment: It's like suggesting using `volatile` for use as a thread-safe construct that can be presented as an alternative to the modern `std::atomic` and `std::condition_variable`. It was the old way of doing things in C land that was highly error prone and "just happened to work" even though now-a-days it should never be used and the modern solutions are better.

Comment: @Casey: I don't think it is appropriate to compare the use of `goto` with using undefined behavior. The use of `goto` has always been well-defined by the ISO C++ standard. I believe the main question at hand is: "Is it cleaner to introduce an extra variable or to introduce a goto label?" I tend to favor the `goto` label in this case, but I respect your opinion if you favor the opposite.